# Bootstrap 3 - How to center Headings and <span>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can i center a heading or something i styled with "span" in a bootstrap3 column ?

if i use "text-center" and "p" tags - everything works fine .. but i need to style the text.

example (works fine):

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center"> <p> hello </p></div>
```

but this doesn't work. i want to change the size and the color of the text and then center it.

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center"> <h1> hello </h1></div>
```

Comment: try adding `text-align: center;` in your div class. I guess as header is block item, `text-center` doesnt work on it. `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="text-align:center">
     <h1> hello </h1>
</div>`

Comment: This centers but you have more classes than needed. <div class="col-md-6 text-center"> <h1> hello </h1></div>  http://jsbin.com/kiqefo/edit. This is to center the text inside the 50% column on large viewports and have a full width column on small viewports. If you want to center the 50% column itself that's different. But the text is centered.

Comment: Your grid column classes are redundant; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

a) apply 'text-center' class to the h1

```
<h1 class="text-center">
```

b) apply this style to h1:

```
h1 {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

The reason that the h1 text isn't centering is because the 'text-center' class of the parent applies to the element h1 and NOT its contents, which occupies the whole width, so you can't center a full width element; it just occupies the whole width.

Applying text-center class on the h1 elements, centers its inner contents.

Applying 'display:inline-block' gives the h1 element a width equal to it's contents, thus it can be centered.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap approach to solving the problem is as follows.

`<h1 class="text-center container-fluid">Heading</h1>`

**Problem**:The H1 tag only spans with width of the text.

**Solution**: The `.container-fluid` will span for the full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Answer (score -1):

This should work if you are looking for a fast solution.

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <center><h1>hello</h1></center>
  </div>
```

If also you could write CSS so that it would override the heading

```
 h1{
     font-family: _______ !important;
     font: ____ !important
     margin:0 auto !important;
 }
```

Comment: Center tag is unnecessary as CSS can easily handle the formatting. Also prefer to avoid using !important except in the most dire cases; it's overkill in this scenario.